# How to transform (convert) absolute screen coordinates to relative view coordinates in Android?

Tags: android, coordinates, android-view, transformation, coordinate-systems

The view may be translated, scaled and rotated, possibly offscreen. How do I go about converting an absolute screen coordinate to that view's local coordinate?

For example, the view has been moved, scaled and rotated, so that parts of it are offscreen. The user clicks in the middle of the screen, generating a MotionEvent with x=500 and y=500 (for simplicity my screen is 1000x1000). How can I find out what (500,500) will be in the local coordinate space of that view?

I've tried attempting it with `View.getLocationOnScreen()` but without success.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue ? Thanks!

Comment: Don't think I did, although I cannot remember this particular part of my code unfortunately. Possibly new solutions appeared since I created this question. Sorry!